# What does this javascript regular expression code do in dealing with URLS?

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking at someone elses codebase and I as a javascript noob and doubly so a regular expression noob I can't figure out what the following lines do:

```
var url = sel.anchorNode.parentNode.href;
var match = self.location.href.replace(/\/$/i, '');
var replaced = url.replace(match,'');
```

I read it as:

1. set the var *url* to the href value of the parent node of the currently selected node
2. sets the var *match* to the browsers current URL with the trailing '/' removed (if it exists)
3. sets the var *replaced* to the string returned in 1. with the string returned in 2. removed from  it

If I am reading it correctly I just can't figure out how it would ever do anything. There isn't any situation, I can think of, where the parent node of a currently selected node would have an href value pointing to the current URL.

So I think I am reading it incorrectly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because the `href` property of an anchor is a fully-resolved URL (even if the `href` attribute is relative), what that does is remove the current page's path and get you back to a relative URL. E.g., on the page:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/
```

with a link like

```html
<a href="nifty.html">...</a>
```

...you get the `href` from the anchor which is:

```
http://example.com/foo/bar/nifty.html
```

...and then remove `http://example.com/foo/bar` from it, giving you:

```
/nifty.html
```

In this case, of course, that's probably not what you actually want. :-) I have to admit I fail to see how the code is useful, out of context, but then context is king sometimes...

Comment: I made this JSfiddle to demonstrate but it does not seem to work like you imply it would: http://jsfiddle.net/funkyeah/WEQZZ/

Comment: It seems like it only chops off the trailing / if there is one and nothing more. How would a regular expression look for line 2 that would do what you describe above?

Comment: @Funkyeah: In your example, your "other" URL isn't relative to your "current URL".

Comment: OK, so it looks like you are saying that only the trailing / is removed and my understanding of your answer was just incorrect. Thanks!